# How to end setTimeout after user input

Tags: javascript, project

Im developing a game in JavaScript in which the user needs to give a key input (press spacebar) when a clock hand moves slightly more than usual.
Currently, I am using a `setTimeout` function that gives the user 1 second to give a key input after the clock hand has ticked (rotated by 10 degrees).
If the user correctly presses space when the clock hand moves more than usual (15 degrees), an indicator will flash green, otherwise it will flash red.

The problem I am running into is that once the user gives an input within 1 second of the hand moving, the indicator will not flash until AFTER that 1 second has passed (ie, if the user gives an input after 0.4 seconds, the indicator will not flash until 0.6 later)

I know this is because the indicator is set up in my `setTimeout` fuction, which will only execute the code after 1 second. I have tried to test for the user input outside of the `setTimeout` function but that way the user does not get 1 second to give a response.

I was wondering if there is a way around this problem or a better way to approach this?

```
//Get input after clock tick

setTimeout(() => {
    if (irregular_tick && space_pressed) {
        flashScreenGreen();
    }
    if (!(space_pressed) && irregular_tick) {
        flashScreenRed();
    }             
},1000);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you need to clear the timeout if the user interupts it and handle your green flash outside of the timeout callback.

Comment: You need to listen to the user input. Something like `element.addEventListener("keydown", function(){ // Kill the setTimeout here if condition is met })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to keep a reference to your timer *outside* of the `setTimeout` callback and add a listener for the keypress with an interrupt callback which will clear the timeout if all conditions are met.

```
let timer = null;
let space_pressed = false;

function reset() {
  timer = null;
  space_pressed = false;
}

function interruptHandler(e) {
  if (timer !== null) { // only look for spacebar if timer is running
    space_pressed = e.key === ' ';

    if (irregular_tick && space_pressed) {
      // clear timeOut if successful
      clearTimeout(timer);
      reset();

      flashScreenGreen();
    }
  }
}

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', interruptHandler);

timer = setTimeout(() => {
  if (!space_pressed && irregular_tick) {
    flashScreenRed();
  }

  // reset timer at end of callback ready for next run
  reset();
}, 1000);
```

---

As a side note it looks like you've defined two separate `flashScreenGreen()` and `flashScreenRed()` functions. I'm guessing that they have similar if not identical logic. If that is the case you might want to consider defining a single utility `flashScreen()` function which accepts a color as a parameter.

```
function flashScreen(color) {
  // logic utilizing 'color'
}

// usage
flashScreen('green');
flashScreen('#FF0000'); // red as hex
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the clearTimeout function will help you here

```
   // Hold the reference to the timer
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    if (irregular_tick && space_pressed) {
        flashScreenGreen();
        //You can use the clearTimeout function to end the timer
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
    if (!(space_pressed) && irregular_tick) {
        flashScreenRed();
        //clear timeout, if you need it here too
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }             
},1000);
```